# How to query a collection that matches the exact fields of objects in array

Tags: mongodb

How to query a collection that matches the exact fields of objects in an array?

Since a test case is more explicit, here is the test to pass.

```rb
a = Invitation.create(guests: [ Guest.new(player: 'bbb'), Guest.new(player: 'ccc') ])
b = Invitation.create(guests: [ Guest.new(player: 'ccc'), Guest.new(player: 'bbb') ])
c = Invitation.create(guests: [ Guest.new(player: 'bbb'), Guest.new(player: 'ccc'), Guest.new(player: 'ddd') ])

# Request to find invitation with bbb and ccc as player_id of guests, regardless the order.
result = Invitation.collection.find(...)
assert_equal result, [ a, b ]
```

My use case is an invitation system where a same combination of guests can't exist, so when a new invitation is sent, i need to check if one with the exact same guests (regardless their order).

Note: I use an array of Guest objects since it carry some additional data. Here is an example data set (https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5507735).

Comment: Can you provide an example of a record from mongo? db.Invitation.findOne() would do the trick.

Comment: I edited the post to add an example data set (https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5507735).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on answer by nyde1319; this feels slightly hackish, but since there's no other answers yet here goes:

```
db.invitation.find({'guests.player':{'$all':['bbb','ccc']}, guests: {$size: 2}})
```

The number 2 in `{$size: 2}` of course depends on the length of array.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [`$all`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/all/) is what you need. I'm not sure which ORM or what schema you are using but here's a sample mongo shell output:

```
> db.invitation.find({'guests.player':{'$all':['bbb','ccc']}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("518319079468428b381d3563"), "guests" : [ { "player" : "bbb" }, { "player" : "ccc" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("518319239468428b381d3566"), "guests" : [ { "player" : "ccc" }, { "player" : "bbb" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("518319b39468428b381d3567"), "guests" : [ { "player" : "ccc" }, { "player" : "bbb" }, { "player" : "ddd" } ] }
```

If you only want those containing `'bbb'` and `'ccc'` only, you can try the following:

```
db.inv.find({'guests.player':{$all:['bbb','ccc']},
  'guests':{$not:{$elemMatch:{'player':{$nin:['bbb','ccc']}}}}})
```

which gives:

```
[ 
  {   "_id" : ObjectId("518319079468428b381d3563"),
      "guests" : [ { "player" : "bbb" },   { "player" : "ccc" } ]   },
  {   "_id" : ObjectId("518319239468428b381d3566"),
      "guests" : [ { "player" : "ccc" },   { "player" : "bbb" } ]   }
]
```

If you want `'bbb'` and `'ccc'`, just replace `$all` with `$in`. This somehow an XOR implementation but I am not sure if it covers all your use case.

Comment: The problem is I don't want the third record. I only want invitations with exact players BBB and CCC (regardless the order). I don't want ones containing BBB, CCC and DDD.

Comment: Thanks. I believe the answer from Juho is a better way to go.